# Deleting a number from an array

Tags: arrays, c

I am trying to delete a number from an array at a given position.

IN MY CODE: **the array has 5 numbers, 3 6 5 2 4 . I want to delete the number at position 2 which is 5. The output after deleting should be 3 6 2 4.** **but I am getting 3 6 2 2 4** any help?

**MY CODE:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(void){
  int n;
  int i;
  int position;
  int a[10];
  printf("Enter how many numbers\n");
  scanf("%d",&n);
  printf("Enter the numbers\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    scanf("%d",&a[i]);
  }
  printf("Enter the position of the number you want to delete\n");
  scanf("%d",&position);

  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    while(i == position){
      a[i] = a[i+1];
      i = i+1;
    }
  }
  printf("Elements after:\n");
  for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    printf("%d ",a[i]);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

[image: OUTPUT]

Comment: The `while` loop exits after one iteration because `i` is incremented, and therefore no longer equal to `position`. Also, after removing an element, you need to decrement `n`,since the count of elements has been reduced.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
// To delete a number from the array, we need to shift all of the
// further numbers down one spot. Note that we start the loop at the
// index of the entry we wish to delete.
for(i = position; i < n; i++) { 
  a[i] = a[i+1];
}

// Once we've completed the shift, the array is now smaller.
n = n - 1;
```

Comment: What about the space for this array allocated in memory? Is it needed to use `realloc()` in this circumstances? Shouldn't we allocate decreased size memory?

Comment: @black: You could. You don't have to. In the question the array is stack allocated so you can't use realloc on that.

Comment: Could you explain a bit more please? What should I use for this case?

Comment: You can't shrink a stack allocated array.

Answer (score 2):

Decrement the size of you array `n` after you are done shifting and also you can achieve this by

```
 for(i = position; i < n; i++) {
    a[i] = a[i+1];
  }
  
  n--;
```